# Convert PHP to JSON with Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP variable I need to convert to JSON string.

I have following PHP code:

```
$username="admin";
$password="p4ssword";
$name="Administrator";
$email="myname@smsfree4all.com" 
$params=compact('username', 'password','name','email', 'groups');
json_encode($params);
```

This works fine. But what I am not sure about is how do I encode the properties in PHP with nested key value pairs shown below:

```
{
"username": "admin",
"password": "p4ssword",
"name": "Administrator",
"email": "admin@example.com",
"properties": {
    "property": [
        {
            "@key": "console.rows_per_page",
            "@value": "user-summary=8"
        },
        {
            "@key": "console.order",
            "@value": "session-summary=1"
        }
    ]
   }
}
```

What is this with @ before key value?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the JSON shown in your question as a PHP object / array?

Comment: Where are you getting that JSON output from? PHP's `json_encode` will encode any variable to JSON, regardless of how nested it is.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I am not sure how to specify the nested arrays (properties) in PHP to pass it into json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
$username="admin"; //more variables
$params=compact('username' /* more variables to be compacted here*/);

$params["properties"] = [ 
  "property" => [
    [
        "@key" => "console.rows_per_page",
        "@value"=> "user-summary=8"
    ],
    [ 
        "@key"=> "console.order",
        "@value"=> "session-summary=1"
    ]
  ]
];

echo json_encode($params);
```

[The manual has more examples you can use](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)

Notice that:

- A key~value array is encoded into an object
- A regular array (array of arrays here) is encoded into an array

Those are all the rules you need to consider to encode any arbitrary object

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$properties = [
    'property' => [
        ['@key' => 'console.rows_per_page', '@value' => 'user-summary=8'],
        ['@key' => 'console.order', '@value' => 'session-summary=1']
    ]
];
```

It's difficult to tell what you're asking.

Comment: thank you!  I will pass $properties to json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

You can nest in PHP using simple arrays, very similar to JavaScript objects:

```
$grandparent = array(
  "person1" => array(
    "name" => "Jeff",
    "children" => array(
      array("name" => "Matt"),
      array("name" => "Bob")
    )
  ), 
  "person2" => array(
    "name" => "Dillan",
    "children" => array()
  )
);
```